# iSCSI LUN on client - ready only permission

Tags: iscsi, targetcli

I have used **targetcli** to create a LUN.

See my config:

```
  
o- / ......................................................................................................................... [...]
  o- backstores .............................................................................................................. [...]
  | o- block .................................................................................................. [Storage Objects: 0]
  | o- fileio ................................................................................................. [Storage Objects: 1]
  | | o- disk1 ............................................................... [/disks/disk1.fileio (200.0MiB) write-thru activated]
  | |   o- alua ................................................................................................... [ALUA Groups: 1]
  | |     o- default_tg_pt_gp ....................................................................... [ALUA state: Active/optimized]
  | o- pscsi .................................................................................................. [Storage Objects: 0]
  | o- ramdisk ................................................................................................ [Storage Objects: 0]
  o- iscsi ............................................................................................................ [Targets: 1]
  | o- iqn.2003-01.org.linux-iscsi.svenshost.x8664:sn.df83287c359b ....................................................... [TPGs: 1]
  |   o- tpg1 .................................................................................................. [gen-acls, no-auth]
  |     o- acls .......................................................................................................... [ACLs: 1]
  |     | o- iqn.2003-01.org.linux-iscsi.svenshost.x8664:sn.df83287c359b .......................................... [Mapped LUNs: 1]
  |     |   o- mapped_lun0 ................................................................................ [lun0 fileio/disk1 (rw)]
  |     o- luns .......................................................................................................... [LUNs: 1]
  |     | o- lun0 .......................................................... [fileio/disk1 (/disks/disk1.fileio) (default_tg_pt_gp)]
  |     o- portals .................................................................................................... [Portals: 1]
  |       o- 0.0.0.0:3260 ..................................................................................................... [OK]
  o- loopback ......................................................................................................... [Targets: 0]
  o- vhost ............................................................................................................ [Targets: 0]
/>
```

I'm able to connect to the iSCSI Portal.

```
Login to [iface: default, target: iqn.2003-01.org.linux-iscsi.svenshost.x8664:sn.df83287c359b, portal: 15.15.130.11,3260] successful.
```

But when I execute a partprobe:

```
# partprobe 
Warning: /dev/sdd kann nicht zum Schreiben geöffnet werden (Das Dateisystem ist nur lesbar). /dev/sdd wurde nur lesbar geöffnet.
// /dev/sdd can not opened for writing, filesystem is only for read-only.
```

How to open for read/write ?

Answer (score 1):

You should add acl of your iSCSI initiator in targetcli. If you are trying to connect iSCSI target to a linux host, check initiator name here: `cat /etc/iscsi/initiatorname.iscsi`

https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-configure-iscsi-target-and-initiator-using-targetcli-in-centos-rhel-7/

It should allow to connect your target to initiator and use it for read and write operations.

You can also use iSCSI target with GUI. StarWind VSAN is a nice example:
https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san